# Why would a <header> tag inherit differently than a div with the id "header"?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page where the links are specified blue by default for most of the body. I speficy it like this (using SASS):

```
a:link {
    color: $link_new; // This is a blue colour
}
```

I have a navigation menu that has a blue background, so just in the header, I want to change the links to white. Up until recently, my header was contained in a DIV tag that had the ID "header". My code is like this:

```
#header a:link {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Recently, I thought I would change the div to be a [`<header>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header). Just change `<div id="header"></div>` to `<header></header>`. So, in my CSS, I have:

```
header a:link {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

But, when I do this, the link text stops being white! I change nothing else, so I don't see how this can be. I reverted the `<header>` back to `<div id="header">`, and my links go back to being white, as they should be.

I don't get it. Does a `<header>` tag inherit differently or something? Why would the header tag pull the colour from the `a:link` declaration, and not the more local `header a:link` declaration?

Here is what the link element looks like under the ` when using the Firefox developer inspector:

[image: header id]

And here is what it looks like with a `<header>` element:

[image: header element]

Comment: Does this help? http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8e4M/) demonstrates that both the `div#header` and `header` fail to change the link color. Could you please share with us a reduced test case that shows your problem?

Comment: @rvighne, I'm having trouble reproducing a test case, but I added some inspector output to my question which hopefully sheds some light. I think the issue is something to do with what is described in that link you provided - I didn't realize IDs had higher authority than elements - but I'm still having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Comment: Thank you, now could you please scroll down the right pane and show us the output? I think you'll be able to figure out your own problem then.

Comment: @rvighne, sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean by "the right pane". If you are referring to the right pane in the images I have in my question which displays the relevant CSS, then that is the entirety of the output. There is no scroll bar, as there is nothing below the `body{}` declaration.

Comment: OK, that's what I meant. Sorry.

Comment: @rvighne, Thank you for your help. I've sort of solved it. I realized that the header needed to also specify the `a:visited` as white. In my test case, the links in question happened to all have been visited, and were reverting to blue. However, while this allows me to go forward, I still am confused as to why `a:visited` did not present itself as a problem until after I changed to the `<header>` element. I think there's still something going on with the hierarchy as explained in the article you linked, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Try this. Do a regex find-and-replace and change `a:[A-Za-z]+` to `a`. (Basically remove all `a:`-something selectors, leaving only bare `a`). Then tell us if the problem is resolved. I gave up using psuedo-selectors on links long ago for these types of problems.

Comment: As you are not using HTML5 version (seeing your Doctype) so you cannot used `header`. As per HTML5 specification `header` is treated as HTML element. So simply change your doctype and use this one `<!DOCTYPE html>`. then you can use `header` element.

Answer (score 2):

As you are not using `HTML5` (by seeing your Doctype) so you cannot used `header` element directly . As per HTML5 specification `header` is treated as HTML element. So simply change your `Doctype` and use this one `<!DOCTYPE html>` then you can use `<header>` element.

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted. This is the right answer. Element header does not exist in XHTML 1.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `:link` after `a`

Like this

```
header a:link {
  color: #fff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Unfortunately, this did not change anything.

Comment: But there *is* `:link` after `a`... check the OP.

Comment: Check [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/krdfx). Here if you comment the code for "header a:link" then the color (yello) of "a:link" will be applied.

Comment: For the second screen shot I can't see "a:link" after the "header a". Which means it is overwriting "header a". so just add :link after "header a".

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a:link to a.

```
header a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Please check the [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gbgB4/28/)

Comment: Thank you for responding. Unfortunately, I tried this, and it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

in first code you written code by using selector '#header a' and after you use `<header>` tag than you give style by using 'header a'
in this case ID's priority is high than class or element selector

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/